# How To Delete PDF name from my MySql Database And PDF File Folder From PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, xampp

I Tried to make a PHP that can View, Download, and Delete PDF file. The View and Download is working fine, but the Delete is not (I want when doing delete both file and database is remove).

```
Here is my table (simpanfile) in database :

Kode : for file id in database as primary key
Nama_File : the name that user input manually when upload file
Nama_Asli_File : the name that follow the real name of the file.
Folder_Berkas : the folder path for the PDF file.
```

Here is my Index.php for View, Download, and Delete

```
    <a href="View.php?url=<?php echo $row['Folder_Berkas']; ?>">Lihat</a> <c> - </c>                            
    <a href="DownloadFile.php?url=<?php echo $row['Folder_Berkas']; ?>">Unduh</a> <c> - </c>    
    <a href="Hapus.php?url=<?php echo $row['Folder_Berkas']; ?>">Hapus</a>
```

So basically, my PHP call the folder path for the file that uploaded to view and download. I tried to delete the file with this code but it's not working.

```
    include "Koneksi.php";
    $edit=$_GET['url'];
    $sql=sprintf("delete from simpanfile where Folder_Berkas=",$edit);
    unlink($_GET["url"]);
    header("location:Index.php?");
```

Any idea how to delete both the info in database and file directly from my PHP ? I'm new to this, and please forgive my bad English.

Comment: Post the code for the delete which table , also do you have the error handling enabled

Comment: I'm sorry not post the code before the stack overflow stop me to do it (show error when I'm post it), I'm update my code now.

Comment: Please use ponly prepared statements to avoid SQL injection and other errors

Comment: can you please give me the full code ? I really dont get it about this

Comment: What are you using mysqli or pdo

Comment: I'm using mysqli and I run it on my localhost.

Comment: "_I tried to delete the file with this code but it's not working_" You'd also need to execute your `$sql` query. And since you don't seem to know how to use `sprintf()` correctly, here's a link with examples https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: I'm surrender, I dont know how to use it. I think this is the end.

Comment: This code is a security disaster - a user can request to delete any file on your server. It needs to have some validation or restriction to specific areas/folders

Comment: `I'm using mysqli`...so then read a good tutorial such as https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli which shows you how to execute queries properly and safely, and also gives you lots of information about good practices in general. You can learn a lot from that.